# dynamic JSON array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using PHP and some JSON arrays to show data from a table. Following code is like following image :

[image]

My prob: I used the following code for offering some packages to my user on an android app. in my `food_category` table, Ids 6-7-8 are drink and meal and dessert. How can I show complete food and drink and meal and dessert in many arrays like the following image that show all information on 1 array? Now my code separates ids and names and ... in some arrays. Can u help me, guys?

[image]

Food table:

[image]

Code:

```
public function package_recommender($restaurant_id, $count, $money)
{
    $response = array();
    $response['success'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "success";
    $connection = null;


    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

    try {
        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", PackageRecommender::DATABASE_NAME);

        $sqlQuery1 = "SELECT * FROM food where NOT foodCategory_id=6 And NOT foodCategory_id=7 And NOT foodCategory_id=8 And restaurant_id='$restaurant_id' And stock>='$count' And isActive = 1;";
        $result1 = $connection->query($sqlQuery1);

        $sqlQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM food WHERE foodCategory_id=7 And restaurant_id = '$restaurant_id' And stock>'$count' And isActive = 1 order by updateDate desc;";
        $result2 = $connection->query($sqlQuery2);


        $sqlQuery3 = "SELECT * FROM food WHERE foodCategory_id=8 And restaurant_id = '$restaurant_id' And isActive = 1 order by updateDate desc;";
        $result3 = $connection->query($sqlQuery3);

        $sqlQuery4 = "SELECT * FROM food WHERE foodCategory_id=6 And restaurant_id = '$restaurant_id' And isActive = 1 order by updateDate desc;";
        $result4 = $connection->query($sqlQuery4);

        $desertArray = $result2->fetch_assoc();
        $drinkArray = $result3->fetch_assoc();
        $mealArray = $result4->fetch_assoc();

        $packagesArray = array();

        if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
            $foodArray = $result1->fetch_assoc();
            foreach ($foodArray as $key => $foodValue) {
                $package = array();
                $package['food'] = $foodValue;

                if (isset($mealArray[$key])) {
                    $package['meal'] = $mealArray[$key];
                }
                if (isset($drinkArray[$key])) {
                    $package['drink'] = $drinkArray[$key];
                }
                if (isset($desertArray[$key])) {
                    $package['desert'] = $desertArray[$key];
                }

                array_push($packagesArray, $package);
            }
            $response["package"] = $packagesArray;
        }

        echo json_encode($response);
    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['message'] = "error 101";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem :)

Comment: what is the criteria of grouping?

Comment: @Suchitkumar Restaurant_id & Count of people & User money. Check question again I edited for showing food table

Comment: @Suchitkumar Please check question's edit. Can you guide me?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm gonna take a huge leap here and assume you have the same number of food, meals, drinks and deserts, and that you only want to display them as a combination ina a package without any particular order or logic.

So looking at your code, you nowhave 4 arrays:

```
$foodArray = array();
$desertArray = array();
$drinkArray = array();
$mealArray = array();
```

And if you want to have a simple combination of them as a package, this would be the easieast way, fisrt you declare a packages array:

```
$packagesArray = array();
```

And then just iterate through one of your array (like food), make a key - value pair, check for other arrays in one foreach loop and add a package:

```
foreach ($foodArray as $key => $foodValue){

    $package = array();
    $package['food'] = $foodValue;

    if(isset($mealArray[$key])){
        $package['meal'] = $mealArray[$key];
    }
    if(isset($drinkArray[$key])){
        $package['drink'] = $drinkArray[$key];
    }
    if(isset($desertArray[$key])){
        $package['desert'] = $desertArray[$key];
    }

    array_push($packagesArray, $package);
}

$response["package"] = $packagesArray;
```

Now, like I said, I have no idea if the packages are in some way related with the food, drinks and meals. This is just a simple example.

Comment: Thx my friend. But I didn't understand. Can you explain more?

Comment: You go through each element of foodArray one by one.  This foreach condition `$foodArray as $key => $foodValue` makes sure you get the index of each element. So when you're on 2nd index of foodArray for example (try `print_f($foodArray);` etc after each sql returned result to see indexes), you check if other arrays have any value at the same index , if they do, you add them in a temporary `$package` array. In the end you push that array into packagesArray (the json_encode maybe shows it as an object if these are simple arrays). At each step of that foreach loop `$package` array is reset.

Comment: Hey, I have some progress on my coding. But I saw another problem. I edited my question. please check again and help me if you have time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you get that array in the first image? Can you show me a few rows of data in the database?

Comment: Ok, I'll probably get annoying here, but can you also show me a data dump or json array of foodArray or desertArray. Any other array than the packaesArray.

Comment: `Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [name] => ????? ??????
    [firstMaterial] => ????? . ???? ?????
    [img] => uploaded-5b72774fa65681.07943267.jpg
    [price] => 380000
    [priceOff] => 0
    [stock] => 150
    [restaurant_id] => 1
    [foodCategory_id] => 1
    [createDate] => 2018-08-14 11:01:43
    [updateDate] => 2018-08-14 11:01:43
    [isActive] => 1
)`

Comment: Is it ok? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I see, so when you get a result from a database, you only get one row. Can you dump this as well `$result3 = $connection->query($sqlQuery3);` that result should be array of arrays, not a single array with parameters. Basically something like this: `Array( [0] => Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => ????? ?????? [firstMaterial] => ????? . ???? ????? [img] => uploaded-5b72774fa65681.07943267.jpg [price] => 380000 [priceOff] => 0 [stock] => 150 [restaurant_id] => 1 [foodCategory_id] => 1 [createDate] => 2018-08-14 11:01:43 [updateDate] => 2018-08-14 11:01:43 [isActive] => 1 ))`.

Comment: Hmm. more explain?

Comment: Don't use this: `$desertArray = $result2->fetch_assoc();`
do it like this for each of the meals type:
`$desertArray = array();
while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
    array_push($desertArray, $row);
}`